# How Magento registers new module?

Tags: magento2, module

While doing

> setup:upgrade

What Magento actually does to register the unregistered module !!,
 Can anyone define the flow?
Actually I want to send a notification to admin whenever a new module is registered.

Any help would be appreciated..!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> While Creating a module we have a registration.php file which consits:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Mageside. All rights reserved.
 * See MS-LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

> To check the Module status:`php bin/magento module:status`
>
> If your Module is in the List of Disabled module then Enable it using:

`php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName`

> Then followed by commands(in ubuntu):

```
    sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
(to upgrade your store with the module)
    sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
(Generates code and dependency injection configuration)
    sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
    sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
    sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/
```

> Now to Check Your Module Status Again use:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

> Your Module Will be now in the list Of enabled Module And Done Your
>   Module is Successfully Registered by magneto

Comment: I am not asking it, you got me wrong I am asking the flow to registration of Module what Magento does! I need to take one of their functionality to implement on it. I want to show last registered module, 
Thanks.